# How to avoid the "Your connection is not private" screen when developing an HTTP2 site locally?

Tags: google-chrome

When I'm developing using Node's http2 library (which only supports HTTPS, not HTTP), when I open localhost in Chrome, I get a warning screen:

> ### Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
>   NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

You have to click "Advanced" then "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)". It gets annoying having to do this during development.

I generated a cert and key for localhost use according to the instructions for Node's [http2 module](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example). Is there any way to generate them in such a way that Chrome would actually accept them for localhost? Or is there another easy way to get rid of this warning?

(I'm aware of the option of launching Chrome with `--ignore-certificate-errors` but I'd prefer not to do this for all websites.)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/930329/configuring-chrome-to-ignore-ssl-warning-on-specific-addresses

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

In Chrome, put in chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost in the address bar.

Enable the option that says "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost".

Restart Chrome, and it should allow the site.

Answer (score 8):

You can also type `thisisunsafe` once you put focus on the website

Answer (score 1):

There are two options you can use to get rid of this annoying thing, which are:

**Temporarily Disable SSL Warning**

You can go to Google Chrome, input chrome://flags in the address bar and press the Enter key to access advanced settings.

In the next step, find the "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" option and enable it. This method is the same as using --ignore-certificate-errors attribute on your Google Chrome shortcut. It disables the SSL warning for all sites.

It's just a temporary solution and I wouldn't suggest to use this frequently.

> (I'm aware of the option of launching Chrome with
>   --ignore-certificate-errors but I'd prefer not to do this for all websites.)

**Install SSL On Your Localhost with OpenSSL**

[image]

You can install SSL on your localhost with OpenSSL. By using this method, your localhost can run HTTPS without any issue at all. The tutorial is quite long with detailed instructions, you can [read it at here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/).

Source: [Fix Your Connection Is Not Private Error In Your Browser - ByteBiteBit.com](https://bytebitebit.com/687/your-connection-is-not-private/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried too many techniques but nothing works at last i find it while i was learning Webapi.

i was unable to visit to any side beacuse of showing the Error "Your Connection is not Private"......

THE REASON IS You have to enable SSL on your Browser and how you can do it let me share the link..
Just follow the steps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hb6iD3nP6g&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=16

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: In referred video, it imports a localhost certificate from Microsoft Management Console, to Trusted Certificated list, then chrome allows browsing without error!

Comment: our organisation, like many, blocks YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

1. `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` in the address bar.
2. set it to `Enabled`

[image: chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost]

3. relaunch chrome
4. result
   [image]